# Creating select modelform based off min and max year present in table?

Tags: django

I am attempting to create a ModelChoiceField who's options are based off finding the years present in a number of posts within the database.

So for example there are posts stored in my database with a `DateTime` field. What i am attempting to do is create a form with the options based on the range of years present in the post table.

## ie

We have a post with field date_created. The value is

> 2013-06-27 03:21:15

and we have another with the value

> 2012-06-27 03:00:20

I want to display a form with select options for each year present in the post table with no duplicates;

```
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
```

Will a ModelChoiceField allow me to do this with a single query or do i need to process and build say a list containing the years.

Comment: If you have a model "Year" you maybe have to pass Year.objecs.all() [the query set], but i think you dont.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to lalo for pointing me in the right direction. I managed to figure it out using the following;

```
    years_list = []
choices = []
year_list = Post.objects.all().values_list('date_created').distinct()

for years_avail in year_list:
    years_list.append(years_avail[0].strftime('%Y'))

for year in years_list:
    choice =(year, year)
    choices.append(choice)

years = forms.ChoiceField(choices, label='')
```

Is this a good way to go about doing this or is this inefficient/wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) is for model select, based in foreign key. I think you have to user [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) and generate the options in runtime.

Show me where you use the form, maybe can show you how to do.